# PayPal Sandbox: testing payment

Tags: paypal-sandbox

I am testing checkout via paypal

Paypal always adds something like this:

```
395&county=6
```

to my return url and its breakes my seo url.

For example, my returning page is

```
 http://mysite.com/pay/success
(<input type="hidden" id="return"  name="return" value="http://mysite.com/pay/success" />)
```

After payment, when i click on "Return to My site Test Store",
i go to

```
http://mysite.com/pay/success395&county=6
```

So, i get 404 page instead my thank you page

Solved. Specific problem on my side. With paypal all fine.

Comment: Have a look at your `.htaccess` file and modify it accordingly.

Comment: Problem is that paypal actually return url is http://mysite.com/pay/success395&county=6 (i viewed by firebug). Looks like paypal adds to my return url county id and id of payment automatically .htaccess and seo urls on my site are all fine